# expected primary-expression before 'return'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, return, expression, conditional-operator

In function 'int v(std::string)':
7:17: error: expected primary-expression before 'return'
7:17: error: expected ':' before 'return'
7:17: error: expected primary-expression before 'return'
8:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int v(string s) 
{
    s.length()? return 1:return 0;
}

int main()
{
    string s="";
    cout<<v(s);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Statements may not be used in expressions.

Rewrite this

```
int v(string s) 
{
    s.length()? return 1:return 0;
}
```

like

```
int v( const string &s ) 
{
    return s.length() != 0;
}
```

or

```
int v(string s) 
{
    return s.length() ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: One is an expression. The other isn't. `return` is a statement, not an expression.

Comment: @Droger Yes it is fine because cout << "1" is an expression. Under the hood it is a function call.